# Disable automatic scroll when typing in TextInput (React-Native - Android)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have set via react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view to scroll the view in my desired position onFocus. However when I start typing, it automatically scrolls to the cursor of the TextInput.

I have important components dynamically render directly below the TextInput which the user needs to choose from, however it gets covered by the keyboard on Android once the user starts typing.

I do not have such issues with iOS.